# Hadoop MapReduce access mapper output number in reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, mapper, reducers

I have a mapper that outputs each letter in a sentence, which is the key, with the number 1, as its value. For example, my mapper outputs 'How are you' as

```
H 1
o 1
w 1
a 1
r 1
e 1
y 1
o 1
u 1
```

My reducer takes this and uses the 1's to count the occurrences of each letter. For example, it would output the letter 'o' as a key and 2 as its value, as it occurs twice.

My issue is i want to calculate the frequency at which each letter occurs in a sentence. To do so, i need the access the total number of letters in the sentence (the mappers number of outputs). I'm new to mapreduce, so i'm not sure the best way to go about this.

Comment: If you have total count of letters in the mapper maybe you can append that value to each output as well? `H 1 9, o 1 9, w 1 9 ...`

Comment: What does your input look like? Each mapper will almost certainly be reading multiple sentences. Typically mappers read one line of data at a time. You don't want the gigantic overhead of spawning up a mapper just to read one sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked it out myself: use the global counter to access MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS to get the total number of mapper outputs in reducer.

Code:

```
Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
Cluster cluster = new Cluster(conf);
Job currentJob = cluster.getJob(context.getJobID());
long totalCharacters = currentJob.getCounters().findCounter(TaskCounter.MAP_OUTPUT_RECORDS).getValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your mapper is getting a complete sentence in which you are trying to find the frequency and you are using Java API, you can output two keys from the mapper through `context.write(...)` function:

java syntax for mapper :  `public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)`

1. Key: `<lineNo_Letter>` ; value: `c_m`
2. key: `<lineNo_Letter>` ; value: `t_n`

where

> ```
> lineNo = same as key to the mapper (the first parameter to the above function)
> letter = your desired letter
> m = <total number of letters in the line (the 2nd parameter to the above function) input to the mapper>
> n = <number of occurrence of letter in the line (the 2nd parameter to the above function) mapper input line>
> ```

`c_` and `a_` are just prefix to identify the type of counts. `c` represents the occurrence of the letter; while `t` represents total number of occurrence.

Basically here we are leveraging the concept that you can write as many key-value you wish from the mapper/reducer.

Now the reducer would get the something like 
Key: `<lineNo_letter>` value: `ListOf[c_m, t_n]`

Now, just iterate on the list, split it with delimiter `_` and with the help of identifier prefix (`t` and `c`); you have desired values in the reducer. i.e.

```
Total number of letter in the sentence = m
Total number of occurrence of the letter = n
```

### **EDIT: Adding psuedo logic**

Taking your example, suppose the input line to the mapper function `public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)` is

```
LongWritable key = 1
Text value = howareyou
```

Output from mapper should be:

```
-- Output length of the Text Value against each letter
context.write("1_h", "t_9");
context.write("1_o", "t_9");
context.write("1_w", "t_9");
context.write("1_a", "t_9");
context.write("1_r", "t_9");
context.write("1_e", "t_9");
context.write("1_y", "t_9");
context.write("1_u", "t_9");
```

Please note that, the above output is once per letter of the sentence from the mapper. That is why letter `o` is output only once (even though it occurs twice in the input).

More output from the mapper code would be

```
-- Output individual letter count in the input text as 
context.write("1_h", "c_1");
context.write("1_o", "c_2");
context.write("1_w", "c_1");
context.write("1_a", "c_1");
context.write("1_r", "c_1");
context.write("1_e", "c_1");
context.write("1_y", "c_1");
context.write("1_u", "c_1");
```

Again, you can see the letter `o` is having value as `c_2` because it occurs twice in the sentence.

Now there will be 8 reducers spawned and each will get one of the below key value pairs:

```
key: "1_h" value: ListOf["t_9", "c_1"]
key: "1_o" value: ListOf["t_9", "c_2"]
key: "1_w" value: ListOf["t_9", "c_1"]
key: "1_a" value: ListOf["t_9", "c_1"]
key: "1_r" value: ListOf["t_9", "c_1"]
key: "1_e" value: ListOf["t_9", "c_1"]
key: "1_y" value: ListOf["t_9", "c_1"]
key: "1_u" value: ListOf["t_9", "c_1"]
```

Now in each of the reducer, split the key to get the line number and the letter.
Iterate through the list of values to extract the total number and letter occurrence.

Frequency of letter `h` in line 1 = `Integer.parseInt("c_1".split("_")[1])/Integer.parseInt("t_9".split("_")[1])`

This is a pseudo logic for you to implement.

Comment: So in my above example, there are 9 letters. I can calculate this count in the mapper, as i increment a variable on every context.write(key, val). My problem is i need this count in the reducer, to calculate the frequency. I have no idea how to get the count from the mapper to the reducer.

Comment: I have added psuedo logic. Basically you do not need to count each letter in a line by `context.write(key, 1)` because all the letters in the sentence can just be counted using a simple `for` loop.

Comment: @Oblivion Could you please accept the answer if it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Don't write each letter immediately as you see it. Count all the characters, then write that total along with the characters.

Then depending on how you wrote the values, your reducer will see

```
o, [(1,9), (1,9)]
```

Sum the ones, and extract any one of the nines, then divide